# LaTeX: left alignment of equation doesn't work

Tags: alignment

I know, there are several instructions and answers how to get a left alignment of equations in LaTeX. I tried a lot of methods, but it seems that there is no method, that solved my problem.

I don't want to use the `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}` method, because I want to align some equations in the center. At the moment, the best solution that fits to my problem was

```
\begin{align*}
        f(k) &=\int^{\infty }_{-\infty } f(t) \cdot e^{-ikt} \cdot \D t \\
    &=\int^{\infty }_{-\infty}\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\omega_{0}  t}+e^{-i\omega_{0} t}\right) \cdot e^{-a|t|} \cdot e^{-ikt} \cdot \D t \\
    &=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty }\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\omega_{0} t} \cdot e^{-ikt} +e^{-i\omega_{0} t} \cdot e^{-ikt}\right) \cdot e^{-a|t|} \cdot \D t \\
    &=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty }\frac{1}{2}\left( e^{i\omega_{0} t - ikt} +e^{-i\omega_{0} t-ikt}\right) \cdot e^{-a|t|} \cdot \D t \\
    &=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty }\frac{1}{2}\left( e^{i(\omega_{0} -k) t} +e^{-i(\omega_{0} +k) t}\right) \cdot e^{-a|t|} \cdot \D t \\ 
    &=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty }\frac{1}{2}\left( e^{i(\omega_{0} -k) t} \cdot e^{-a|t|} +e^{-i( \omega_{0} +k) t} \cdot e^{-a|t|}\right) \cdot \D t \\
    &=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty } e^{i(\omega_{0} -k) t-a|t|} \cdot \D t + \frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty }_{-\infty} e^{-i(\omega_{0} +k) t-a|t|} \cdot \D t \\
    \Rightarrow f(k) =\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty }_{-\infty } e^{i(\omega_{0} -k) t-a|t|} \cdot \D t + \frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty }_{-\infty } e^{i( -( \omega_{0} +k)) t-a|t|} \cdotp \D t
\end{align*}
```

The result I get is this:

[image: 1]]

What I want is to remove the empty area (which I marked as a red square in this picture)

[image]

so that the equation starts really at the left.

When I write `\begin{align*} \item f(k)` etc. I get my left alignment, but the equations look very squashed and ugly.

[image]

You can find my full LaTeX code here: 
https://www.overleaf.com/read/nkhmhfrhcwzy

I'm very grateful for your answers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!

Comment: You are missing an alignment point in the last line, so LaTeX thinks that the whole equation is in the first column. That's why it's so big. Use `\Rightarrow f(k) &=\frac{1}{2}...` in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

The `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` is here for that. Note that if most of your equations are left aligned, you might as well use the `fleqn` option for the document class and use the `ceqn` environment for centred equations.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\newcommand*{\D}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
    f(k) &=\int^{\infty }_{-\infty } f(t) \cdot e^{-ikt} \cdot \D t \\
&=\int^{\infty }_{-\infty}\mfrac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\omega_{0} t}+e^{-i\omega_{0} t}\right) \cdot e^{-a|t|} \cdot e^{-ikt} \cdot \D t \\
&=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty }\mfrac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\omega_{0} t} \cdot e^{-ikt} +e^{-i\omega_{0} t} \cdot e^{-ikt}\right) \cdot e^{-a|t|} \cdot \D t \\
&=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty }\mfrac{1}{2}\left( e^{i\omega_{0} t - ikt} +e^{-i\omega_{0} t-ikt}\right) \cdot e^{-a|t|} \cdot \D t \\
&=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty }\mfrac{1}{2}\left( e^{i(\omega_{0} -k) t} +e^{-i(\omega_{0} +k) t}\right) \cdot e^{-a|t|} \cdot \D t \\
&=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty }\mfrac{1}{2}\left( e^{i(\omega_{0} -k) t} \cdot e^{-a|t|} +e^{-i( \omega_{0} +k) t} \cdot e^{-a|t|}\right) \cdot \D t \\
&=\mfrac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty } e^{i(\omega_{0} -k) t-a|t|} \cdot \D t + \mfrac{1}{2}\int^{\infty }_{-\infty} e^{-i(\omega_{0} +k) t-a|t|} \cdot \D t \\
\Rightarrow f(k) & =\mfrac{1}{2}\int^{\infty }_{-\infty } e^{i(\omega_{0} -k) t-a|t|} \cdot \D t + \mfrac{1}{2}\int^{\infty }_{-\infty } e^{i( -( \omega_{0} +k)) t-a|t|} \cdotp \D t
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, I just forgot to include the result on the following line. 'Tis fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much! <3
You saved my homework!